Files last modified date changed when saved on CSV (Clustered Storage Volume) runnig on Azure Shared Disk
We implemented a Cluster Shared Volume (CSV) using Azure VMs and Azure Shared Disks. The CSV is accessible for read/write operations from two servers in a failover cluster configuration. This setup is built on two identical Windows Server 2022 machines, fully updated. The failover cluster is configured in a workgroup (non-domain joined) environment.
We observed unexpected behavior when copying files to the CSV. Specifically, most (but not all) of the files have their "last modified" timestamp immediately updated to the current date and time. The issue occurs inconsistently, affecting random files during each attempt.
Using Process Monitor, we identified that the problematic operation is SetBasicInformationFile, performed by the SYSTEM process controlled by the failover cluster. This operation provides the following values:
CreationTime: 1/1/1601 12:59:59 AM
LastAccessTime: 1/1/1601 12:59:59 AM
The result is that the "last modified" timestamp of affected files is overwritten with the current time.
Observations:
The issue disappears when the CSV is switched into maintenance mode.
Formatting the underlying shared disk with ReFS (before converting it to CSV) resolves the issue completely. When using ReFS, the timestamps remain unaffected.
The issue is consistently reproducible with NTFS-formatted shared disks when added to the CSV.
Challenge:
While ReFS appears to resolve the problem, we prefer to use NTFS as it aligns with our standard practices and requirements.
Has anyone encountered similar behavior or can provide insights into why this occurs with NTFS-formatted CSVs? Any recommendations or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
